# How to maximize Peltier devices' cooling capacity?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, semiconductor-physics, experimental-technique, thermoelectricity

I am currently working on a project requiring the use of Peltier devices. I have attached the cool side of the device to a copper plate and the hot side to a heat sink with a fan.

1. What would be the best way to isolate the copper plate from the hot side?
2. Should I leave it at ease with just air in between them?
3. Or will it be better to put styro to insulate the plate that is cooler?

Comment: Maybe [electronics.se] would be a better place to ask this question?

Answer (score 1):

inside the device, the cool side is already in physical contact with the hot side: they form a junction through which electricity is flowing, and it is that flow of electricity which makes one side of the junction get hot and the other side cold.  the very best you can do to maximize the usefulness of a peltier thermojunction is to put fins and fans on both sides of the junction so as to get as much of the heat out of the hot side and cold out of the cold side (so to speak). indeed, the cold side needs to be well-insulated too so the cooling effect is not lost to the environment. styrofoam is good for this, as you point out.

Comment: Aside from a Styrofoam, is there other materials that i can put in between the two plates?

Comment: light wood like cedar is also a good insulator but styrofoam is cheap and easily cut with knives or wood saws.